# Why does water splash if you put it into a hot pan?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

I had kept my tea pan on the stove (At high)for about 30seconds . I was making tea and getting the water to put in the tea pan. There was nothing in it before that .After that , I quickly poured some water in it and boom.

The pan kind of like jumped out of the stove. The water from the pan instantly became steam and some droplets of water touched my kitchen ceiling.

The scene looked like a bomb exploding. As a single droplet of water just touched the pan , the pan just went of control.

Also , you hear a very noisy sound if you do it.

What could be reason for this little amount doing such a reaction ?

Yes, I do not advise kids to do without parents or some elders support.

[image]

Comment: Google: Leidenfrost effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pour water on a very hot plate, much hotter than $100°$C, the water cannot touch the plate. It boils immediately, even before touching the plate. This makes a sudden and huge production of vapor, which takes much more room than a liquid : this throws the rest of the water anywhere in the vicinity with a great speed. It looks like an explosion. Some water may even be thrown to the ceiling.

Another famous experiment can be done directly on the electric plate, without a pan. If you pour maybe one milliliter water on a red hot plate, which has a small cavity in its center, the water floats above the plate in the cavity without touching it. For a couple of seconds, the vapor produced is not strong enough to eject the drop, which stays calmly in levitation. This effect is called Leidenfrost effect, or calefaction.

Comment: Ok. But how is it that vapor is able to move the pan?

Comment: I don't know the form and the geometry of your pan. Is it like a kettle ? Probably the hot water was ejected with such a high speed that it touched the upper part of the kettle, and pushed it away.

Comment: I have added an picture in edit for the pan.

Comment: @Srijansingh7 it must be some asymmetry in the way water was ejected, ie pushing the wall in one preferable direction